# Multivariate Distributions: transformation

Tags: calculus, statistics

If $p(x1,x2)=\frac{2}{3}^{x1+x2}\frac{1}{3}^{2-x1-x2}, (x1,x2)= (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1),$ zero elsewhere, is the joint pmf of $X1$ and $X2$, find the joint pmf of $Y1=X1-X2$ and $Y2=X1+X2$.

How to transform this to make new x1 and x2? Because then i can take a derivative with old x1 and x2 and new x1 and x2 and make Jacobian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

${{x}_{1}}=\frac{{{y}_{1}}+{{y}_{2}}}{2},~{{x}_{2}}=\frac{{{y}_{1}}-{{y}_{2}}}{2}$.

from $\mathcal{A}:0\le {{x}_{1}}\le 1,~0\le {{x}_{2}}\le 1$ to $\mathcal{B}:0\le \frac{{{y}_{1}}+{{y}_{2}}}{2}\le 1,~0\le \frac{{{y}_{1}}-{{y}_{2}}}{2}\le 1$. solving this we get $-{{y}_{1}}\le {{y}_{2}}\le 2-{{y}_{1}}$ and $-2+{{y}_{1}}\le {{y}_{2}}\le {{y}_{1}}$. draw this region.  split this region into two region: first $0\le {{y}_{1}}\le 1,~-{{y}_{1}}\le {{y}_{2}}\le {{y}_{1}}$ second $1\le {{y}_{1}}\le 2,~~{{y}_{1}}-2\le {{y}_{2}}\le 2-{{y}_{1}}$. using these, take integral and get the pdf.